# How can I write a velocity field to a VTI image with anaconda Python?

Tags: python, vtk, anaconda

I am trying to write a VTK Image Data file (.vti) with python. For my python coding I am using the Anaconda distribution. I am using the evtk package, which has the ability to write a vtk file.

The data I need to write is a velocity for which I have the 3d X,Y,Z and U,V,W 3d arrays. I have found some sample code which uses the evtk package to write a .vti file.(http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Writing_VTK_files_using_python)

The problem is that the sample code and built in functions only take scalar point or cell data. So I am able to write a file with scalars, but I need it to have the data as vectors.

I am digging through the actual package files and trying to find a solution or tools to code one.I would extremely appreciate if somebody had suggestions or solutions to give me a hand.

I enclose the test code I have written from info on the wiki just in case I am missing a way of inputing to the function, but I fear I am going to need to start from scratch.

Thanks in advance

(removed the code since the one bellow is more recent)

Managed to write an unstructured file (.vtu), but I would really like to be a able to write an Image Data file.(Found the following link helpful during the process. http://www.aero.iitb.ac.in/~prabhu/tmp/python_cep07/course_handouts/viz3d_handout.pdf)

Thanks again in advance

I attach the code to see if anybody has any suggestions.

```
from tvtk.api import tvtk, write_data
```

import numpy as N

```
##Generation of data
#array of x,y,z coordinates
[Z,Y,X] = N.mgrid[-2.:2+1, -2.:2+1, -2.:2+1]
#array of zeros to add the u,v,w components 
[W,V,U] = N.zeros_like([Z,Y,X],dtype=float) 
#loop through data to have correct format
points = N.array([N.zeros(3) for i in range(len(Z)*len(Z[0])*len(Z[0][0]))])
velF = N.zeros_like(points)
c=0
for k in range(len(Z)):
    for j in range(len(Z[0])):
        for i in range(len(Z[0][0])):
            #coordinates of point
            x = X[k][j][i]
            y = Y[k][j][i]
            z = Z[k][j][i]
            points[c] = N.array([x,y,z])
            #test velocity field               
            u = k -2.
            v = 0.
            w = 0.
            velF[c] = N.array([u,v,w])
            #update counter            
            c = c+1
##Generate and write the vtk file    
Ugrid = tvtk.UnstructuredGrid()
Ugrid.points = points
Ugrid.point_data.vectors = velF
Ugrid.point_data.vectors.name = 'velocity'
write_data(Ugrid, 'vtktest.vtu')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the unstructured grids using **evtk**, here you can find a full demo with point and cell data (both vector and scalar fields): https://gist.github.com/dromanov/0fb8bacff5342a56a690.

Description of the technique and explanations are here: http://spikard.blogspot.ru/2015/07/visualization-of-unstructured-grid-data.html.

Good luck!